# Is "It is these two issues that we need to pay attention to." a correct sentence?

Tags: emphasis, verb-agreement

I hear many native speakers do say sentences that do not strictly follow the subject-verb agreement grammar rules. (This is off-topic, but do they do it without realizing it?)

But in writing, this shouldn't be the case. So I'm wondering how to phrase the sentence in the title. I cannot specify the exact reason, but I can sense that there is a difference in how the two sentences sound:

> 1. We need to pay attention to these two issues.
> 2. It is these two issues that we need to pay attention to.

For me, the latter seems to emphasize the issues after mentioning the issues beforehand, whereas the former just sounds weaker.

According to the subject-verb agreement, the latter should be written in other form. But how?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you see a lack of "subject-verb agreement"?

Comment: @HotLicks Shouldn't 'It' refer to a singular? To me, 'it' and 'two issues' are mismatched. To make the sentence grammatically correct, I feel like I have to write 'They are these two issues that we need to pay attention to' instead. Thanks.

Comment: "It" refers to a matter of concern.  That matter of concern is the two issues.

Comment: @HotLicks So, it would be also correct to say, "What's important is the two previously mentioned issues."?

Comment: Yep, that would be fine.

Comment: This is a Cleft sentence, formed from _We need to pay attention to these two issues_ by a regular rule that inserts a dummy _it_ as the subject, an equative _is_ as the verb, puts the object _these two issues_ right after the fulcrum, and backgrounds the rest of the verb phrase into a restrictive relative that modifies the object. It is **not** the subject; it's a cog in a rather complicated restructuring.

Comment: The sentence beginning _What's important is ..._ is a Pseudo-Cleft sentence. [As Chuck Fillmore put it](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/fillmore.html), Cleft sentences have IT in front; pseudo-cleft sentences has WHAT in front. There are lots more kinds of cleavage; see, for instance, [this variety](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf), the "Nobbut-Cleft".

Comment: @JohnLawler - I'll grant you that cleavage is important, but it seems like an entirely different issue.

Comment: 'I hear many native speakers do say sentences that do not strictly follow the subject-verb agreement grammar rules.'  Are you sure you know all the 'rules'? 'The team were fighting amongst themselves', 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal',  'More than one person was involved' and 'One or more is/are coming' are all acceptable. What 'rules' make sense of these diverse examples?

Comment: An alternative construction to "It is these two issues that we need to pay attention to" that—to me—sounds more conversational and less wooden is "These are the two issues we need to pay attention to." It maintains the structural emphasis of the "It is these..." sentence without the ponderousness of that sentence. [Late addition: I see that Sankarene suggested this very wording (though with a comma I wouldn't use) in an answer below, so I will upvote that answer.]

Answer (score 1):

The second statement, "It is these two issues that we need to pay attention to." is yet another way of saying the same, but as you say, with an emphasis on 'these two issues'. When spoken, it sounds very effective.

Your enquiry on the subject-verb agreement, since it's a complex sentence, consisting of two clauses, here's what I think:

Clauses (2): it is these two issues, we need to pay attention to

Subjects (2): it, we

Verbs (2): to be, need (to pay - infinitive used after 'need')

It - is; we - need

Therefore, as for the question of whether the sentence violates any rules of grammar, I believe the answer is "no", although I'd like to re-phrase the same as follows:

These are the two issues, (that) we need to pay attention to.

Comment: Thanks. I came up with another question. How about the sentence: "It is these two issues that needs particular attention."? Does "needs" need to be replaced by "need"?

Comment: Yes, because 'two issues' (subject) agrees with 'need'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonably good explanation of [the "it-cleft" sentence](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/It-Cleft.htm), with some good examples.  Most often this structure is used for emphasis:

"Joe stole the money."
"No, it was Charley who stole the money."

I agree that "It is these two issues that we need to pay attention to" is a bit infelicitous, not only because of the seeming agreement problem but also because of the repeated two-to-to. I'd probably revise this sentence, as others have suggested.